# Spinning orientation when going to next storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, orientation, spinning

So I've been trying to put off posting here about this because it's such a stupid thing and I imagine it's going to be a simple fix but I honestly cannot find the answer.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SbMBCSQegpw&feature=youtube_gdata_player

This is what keeps happening in the iPad application I'm building.

I have 2 ViewControllers, when I clicked my UIButton to transition to the next Controller, it does the above.

Orientation for each controller is set to landscape and project settings are all set to left only.

I have code in both my .m files to set the orientation to left as well but nothing seems to stop it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have checked the orientation buttons in the project level at the first screen. You might be only having one orientation locked and in code you have the orientation in the opposite way. Like button orientation landscape left and code landscape right.